# Selenium element not always becoming clickable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing some UI automated tests with Java using Selenium page objects.

I'm having some problems with one element on the page. The element in question is a clickable panel which will expand once clicked and reveal some fields and other items of UI that were previously hidden. When the panel is clicked once more the the fields revert to being hidden again.

The problem I have is when I initiate the click on the panel it will sometimes show the previously hidden fields and other times it will show them but very quickly hide them again. This will then make my next action, to click one of the previously hidden fields, fail as the field is not present.

I have an explicit wait on both fields present using `elementToBeClickable`.

I'm thinking that the best way to tackle this is to write a return method that checks if the hidden field is there or not and if the method returns false then initiate the click to the panel again. I display if TRUE or FALSE is returned and I can some cases where FALSE is returned where this fix works as it goes on to expand the panel correctly but I still get cases where it doesn't work.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to solve this.

Below is my code:

```
//this is my method to click the pannel
public void clickPanel() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(panelLink));
    element.click();

   //call another method to see if the hidden field is visible or not
   boolean isHiddenLinkPresent = methodToCheckIfLinkPresent();

   //show the results of if the field is hidden or not
   System.out.println(isHiddenLinkPresent);

    //if link is not present, try and click again
    if (isHiddenLinkPresent == false){
        element.click();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: @IshitaShah I get a 'Unable to locate element' on the next field because it still stays hidden. But only sometimes which is the frustrating bit!

Comment: You need to share block of code, With Target element and before that.

Comment: Better use if/esle statement. If desired element not visible, click panelLink, else nothing. if (ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.visibilityofelementLocated(...

Comment: Relevant HTML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to guess that your javscript hasnt executed on page before the click happens. You probably need to refine your wait code to make sure the js has definitely executed before Selenium continues. You can use a great big dirty

Thread.wait(10000);

to validate that assumption at cert parts of your code but dont leave it in place as that will obviously kill your test suite speed. Without seeing more of your code its hard to completely reproduce the issue locally so you might want to post some more code. Your wait methods for example and a snippet of the html and javascript.

Id also take a look at https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/

the above link gives some detail on waiting for js .. theres a javscript executor you can use to do that. HTH.

Comment: Good shout. After adding in a wait before clicking element all tests now pass rather than the odd few failing at that point. So now I need to find out why. Cheers!